# No sound with Philips SAA7130 Hybrid Capture Device card

Tags: sound, video-capture-card

I have put a Philips SAA7130 Hybrid Capture Device card in a PCI slot. Also I have installed TVtime Television Viewer. I have received video, but I can't get audio. Please help step by step to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english .... but i want to help others in this problem

I found a solution for this problem

First we must understand How this card is working, it pipe the sound from the source to the computer sound card, so we can check to see if there is sounds getting out of it bu plugging a head set in the card out ... if there is a sound then the card is working fine

Second we must deal with the input of the sound card, I download a driver of my sound card for linux.

Third i type "alsamixer" in the terminal and make sure automute is disabled and all volume are in high position

Forth i try all different input sockets in the sound card and the sound is working fine

Hope this will be enough

Answer (score -4):

same as above

Trying all the program options and do some googling about this common problem

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @user237811 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You've posted this as an answer, but it's not an attempt to answer the original poster's question, so it [may be removed soon](http://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion). If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button (upper right). Once you have enough rep, [you may upvote](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers. Please note that Ask Ubuntu is a question-answer site and [works *very differently* from a forum](http://askubuntu.com/about).